# Disable horizontal overscroll on iOS with phonegap or not

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, overscroll

I work with angularjs and phonegap.
I want to create an UI containing a slider.

The problem is, when I use the slider, the content scrolls to the left or to the right (see the pictures).

**Normal state**

[image: Normal state]

**When I try to use the slider**

[image: When I try to use the slider]

Catching the `touchmove` event on the body is not acceptable because I want vertical scroll to work, though.

Thx all.

Comment: Don't you mean vertical?

Comment: No the horizontal scroll ( i update the topic )

Answer (score 2):

do you mean the right scroll bar?
To disable the horizontal scrolling use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`
With this Tag you can't scroll in horizontal way or zoom in.
Or you try `overflow-x: hidden;` or `overflow-y: hidden;` to hide the overflow in one direction.
Hope that helped you.

Comment: I rate the `overflow-x: hidden;` suggestion :) Nice answer

Comment: i use this meta and that dont work, and on my css body i have overflow: hidden. My scrollbar is create with the librairy iscroll

Comment: I apply on the body and the element is on my body. i forget one information, that works on Android phone or tablet, the problem appear only on IOS device.

Comment: Do you mean the space between border an your content?

Comment: Can you set the html an body width: 100vw; and overflow-x: hidden; try this out, and tell me the result or send me a link of the project, so I have better overview of the problem.